# Mongodb how to replace for GROUP_CONCAT in mysql

Tags: mysql, mongodb

This is mongo shell

```js
db.product.aggregate([
   
    {
        $lookup:{
            from: "orders",
             let: { id: "$_id" ,multiId:"$multi_id"},
            as: "orders1",
             pipeline:[{ $match:{ $expr:{ $and:[
                          {$in:[{$substr:["$pid",0,-1]},{ $split:["$$multiId",","] }  ]}
                        ]
                     }
                     }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
  
    {
        $project:{
            price:1,
            orders:1,
            multi_id:1,
            orders1:1
        }
    },
])
```

and the result is:

[image: This is the result]

but I hope the result is: (how to convert the array "orders" to String)

[This is a result what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkiZh.png)

Comment: I want to convert array "orders1" to String

Comment: `I want to convert array "orders1" to String` mentioned this in your question

Comment: There's no difference between the desired and actual result.

Comment: {
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "price" : 15.0,
    "multi_id" : "1,2",
    "orders1" : " 
        {
            "_id" : 1.0,
            "pid" : 1.0,
            "ordername" : "订单1",
            "p_multi_id" : "1"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 2.0,
            "pid" : 2.0,
            "ordername" : "订单2"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : 3.0,
            "pid" : 1.0,
            "ordername" : "订单3"
        }
   "
}

Comment: just replace ‘[' to  ' " '，